# How to replace a variable in yml file with a gitlab ci pipeline variable using sed

Tags: sed, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to replace a variable in my .yml file with a variable from the gitlab ci pipeline.

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
deploy_test:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - sed -i 's/$TAG/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME/g' deploy/test.yml
    - kubectl apply -f deploy/test.yml
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
    - tags
```

This says within the deploy/test.yml file it should replace $TAG with the value of $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME?

**deploy/test.yml**

```
image: git.<removed>.com:5005/eng/my-group/my-image:$TAG
```

Comment: Are those variables available in the environment for the script commands: if yes, you might want to do `sh -c 'sed -i "s/$TAG/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME/g" deploy/test.yml'` -- specifically invoking a shell allows you to know that variable substitution is going to work, and using double quotes for the body will allow the variables to be substituted.

Comment: @glennjackman  ye the $CI_ variable is available in my pipeline but instead of it replacing $TAG with the value of the variable it justy replaces it with the name

Comment: Oh, I see, the literal string `$TAG` appears in the yaml file. Try this: `sed -i 's/$TAG/'"$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"'/g' deploy/test.yml` -- that mix of single and double quotes will keep `$TAG` literal, and the $CI... variable gets substituted.

Comment: @glennjackman By substituted you mean it will use the value of variable $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME? rather than the variable name?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: @glennjackman worked thank you

Comment: @glennjackman this should be an answer, this helped me too

Answer (score 10):

Use double quotes(`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`) in sed and also take note that forward slashes (`/`) need to be escaped too (like `\/`).

so given the following (assuming you are using docker hub)

```
$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=docker_user/repo:v1
```

You will firstly need to escape the '/' character first, like so

```
$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=docker_user\/repo:v1
```

Then finally use double quotes in the sed command

```
sed -i "s/$TAG/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME/g" deploy/test.yml
```

**Note:** In addition to this you can also prefer using `|` instead of `/` if there's too many escapes.

Like:

```
sed -i "s|$TAG|$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME|g" deploy/test.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string consists of / , as a workaroud you can use different delimiting character instead of /
for example,

```
sed -i -E "s%BASE_URL: '.*'%BASE_URL: '\$BACKEND_URL'%g" $FRONTEND_PATH/app/config/index.js
```

Here I am using % as delimiting character as none of my strings has that character, you can use any other depending on the symbols used in your strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
- sed -i "s|TAG|${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}|g" deploy/test.yml
```

and for simpler situation remove the $ from $TAG, so the deploy/test.yml:

```
image: git.<removed>.com:5005/eng/my-group/my-image:TAG
```